# Substituição de caracter usando CMD gerando espaço no fim da linha

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Tenho o script abaixo, que faz a leitura de um arquivo txt, com a estrutura abaixo (sem espaços):

```
260975401:472302202311
261436303:222302202310
101041805:022302202310
101111605:022302202310
101156305:062302202311
100808205:082302202311
```

O arquivo precisa ser tratado para trocar o 1 e o 2 inicial por E ou S, devido a regra sistemica. Desenvolvemos o script abaixo, mas agora ao executar o mesmo ele cria vários espaços no final da linha, e consequentemente nao conseguimos fazer a inserção no sistema de destino:

```
@echo off   
REM Desabilita a exibição dos comandos na tela.

REM Habilita a expansão adiada de variáveis.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion   

REM Itera sobre cada arquivo .txt no diretório atual.
for %%f in (*.txt) do (   
    
    REM Cria uma variável com o nome do novo arquivo.
    set "outfile=%%~nf_editado.txt"   
    
    REM Exclui o novo arquivo se ele já existir.
    if exist "!outfile!" del "!outfile!"   
    
    REM Itera sobre cada linha do arquivo.
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~f") do (   
        
        REM Armazena a linha atual em uma variável.
        set "line=%%a"   
        
        REM Extrai o primeiro caractere da linha.
        set "first_char=!line:~0,1!"   
        
        REM Se o primeiro caractere for 1:
        if !first_char! equ 1 (   
            
            REM Substitui o primeiro caractere por "E".
            set "line=E!line:~1!"   
            
        REM Se o primeiro caractere for 2:
        ) else if !first_char! equ 2 (   
            
            REM Substitui o primeiro caractere por "S".
            set "line=S!line:~1!"   

        )
        REM Escreve a linha modificada no novo arquivo.
        echo !line!>>"!outfile!"   
        
    )
    REM Substitui o arquivo original pelo novo arquivo.
    move /y "!outfile!" "%%~nf.txt" >nul   

)
```

A saida fica com o espaço, mostrado abaixo no destaque (4 casas):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de fazer uma espécie de **trim** na linha, para que todas saiam sem espaço após essa troca feita com o código acima? Ou tem algo errado no código?

Comment: Posso saber o motivo do -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você colocou uns espaços extras na parte onde você passa o texto para o novo arquivo em:

```
echo !line!>>"!outfile!"
```

Depois de "!outfile!" é só remover aqueles espaços que vai sair correto no arquivo final...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara, sem palavras. Eu me batendo nisso a 2 dias. PQP. Muito obrigado!